# Find $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_\alpha(x)$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, let $f_\alpha:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be the function given by: $$f_\alpha(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^\alpha x e^{-nx}.$$
Now I want to find values of $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ for which the function $f_\alpha$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$.

For $\alpha<0$, I used the Weierstrass M-test to prove that $f_\alpha$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$. We see that $f_0(x) = \frac{x}{e^x-1}$ which is continuous. But I am stuck to find $\alpha>0$ such that $f_\alpha$ is continuous. Only thing I see is that $f_\alpha\geq f_0$ for $\alpha>0$.

Furthermore, I want to find values of $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ for which the function $f_\alpha$ is integrable with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $[0,\infty)$. Here I know that $f$ is measurable if $f$ is continuous, but I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $S_{n,\alpha}$ define for $x \in \left[0,+\infty \right[$ by
$$
S_{n,\alpha}\left(x\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{\alpha}xe^{-kx}
$$
Can you find its supremum in $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ ?

Comment: I don't see how I can use this to prove continuity

Comment: Do you know uniform convergence ? The function $S_{n,\alpha}$ is continous on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ hence if there is uniform convergence ( implictly to $\displaystyle f_{\alpha}$ ), you deduce that $\displaystyle f_{\alpha}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$.